# How to display and capture webcam stream at the same time?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, mpeg

This command works perfectly for saving a webcam stream to a file:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -itsoffset 00:00:00 -f video4linux2 -s 1280x720 -r 25 -i /dev/video0  out.avi
```

How would I simultaneously display this captured stream on my computer screen?

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for the same command and the one from @llogan works, but with no audio. This is the command I started to use to capture with video in good quality and with audio.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 \
    -framerate 30 \
    -video_size 1024x768 \
    -input_format mjpeg \
    -i /dev/video0 \
    -f alsa \
    -i hw:2,0 \
    -c:a pcm_s16le \
    -c:v mjpeg \
    -b:v 64000k \
    output.avi \
    -map 0:v \
    -vf "format=yuv420p" \
    -f xv display
```

Maybe you want to see video as a mirror. If so, you have to add `hflip` to the video filter. Use `-vf "format=yuv420p,hflip"`.

I prefer to use pulseaudio as audio input, so I can change it with `pavucontrol` on the fly. Instead of `-f alsa -i hw:2,0`, I use `-f pulse -i alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_22F75AFF-02.analog-stereo` that it is my webcam microphone. To know what your audio source input is, check [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/PulseAudio).

Source: Answer from @llogan and [ffmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-Examples-12).

[EDIT]: I changed part of the code to **get rip of the 1 second lag** that `-f tee` generates. This method, instead of that option, directly encodes to file, changes format to `yuv420p` (accepted by display) and uses `-f xv display` to display video to screen.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee):

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -map 0 -c:v libx264 -f tee "output.mp4|[f=nut]pipe:" | ffplay pipe:
```

Comment: I don't understand this error... `Output file #0 does not contain any stream
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input`
Uh, of course output file doesn't contain any stream **I'm telling you (ffmpeg) to CREATE it!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe it with [`ffplay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html) which comes bundled with the **ffmpeg** package.

> As `llogan` mentioned, use the **tee** muxer/demuxer (aka) container!

```sh
# Redirect the 'ffmpeg' ouput to 'ffplay' input
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -itsoffset 00:00:00 -f video4linux2 -s 1280x720 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f tee "out.avi|[f=nut]-" | ffplay -
```

---

Comment: This won't capture the stream at the same time as requested by the question.

Comment: I just posted that what I know!
What to Improve ?

Comment: I added an answer that uses the tee muxer.

Comment: What special about it ?

Comment: It uses one encoding to create multiple outputs (one for capture and one piped for display in this case). It is more efficient than encoding two separate outputs.

Comment: I think I could add as much pipes as I want ?

Comment: Perhaps with named pipes (`mkfifo` command).